# What is written on this watch?

Tags: перевод

This is a pocket watch. I think it is Russian. But I am not sure, can anybody read this?!

[image]

Comment: It is "Molnia" meaning "Lightning", it is a logo of the producer.

Answer (score 17):

It's Молния (Lightning). I believe such font was very popular in 60-es in the Soviet Union. You could see it on many logos like on cars Москвич, [Чайка](http://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C)), [Волга](http://gaz-24.com/), on the [Янтарь](http://63.img.avito.st/640x480/548282563.jpg) clock, or on a refrigerator [МИР](http://photo.qip.ru/users/retro321/81923/1208700/full_image/).

Comment: You may want to add that is means _"lightning"_ in English.

Comment: A similar style, with blocky "handwriting" letters connected by long underlines evoking speed and modernity, was also popular in the west, although it seems to have peaked a bit earlier there, and been particularly associated with automobiles. See [e.g.](http://chromeography.com/post/89602714036) [these](http://chromeography.com/post/30908963516) [examples](http://chromeography.com/post/91345498696) and [plenty of others](http://chromeography.com/tagged/baseline-connection). It's even recognizable enough [to be used to symbolize automobile design](http://chromeography.com/post/83672266195).